# create a calculator division

Tags: python, division

I have the below code and when I type calculate(2, 0, "/") I would like to print "Division with zero" than just the output, when I divide with 0. Any suggestions?

```
def calculate(num1, num2, operator):
    if operator == "/" or operator == 'divide':
        output = float(num1) / float(num2) if float(num2) else 0
        return output
```

Comment: Well, right now, what happens when `num2` is zero? What part of your code makes that happen? Can you think of a way to change that part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest allowing `calculate` to raise `ZeroDivisionError` and having the caller print the error:

```
def calculate(num1, num2, operator):
    if operator == "/" or operator == 'divide':
        return num1 / num2

try:
    print(calculate(2, 0, "/"))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Division with zero")
```

That way you aren't having one function either return or print depending on the situation -- `calculate` always computes a result (which might include a `ZeroDivisionError`) without printing it, and the calling code is always in charge of printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an additional condition handling the case you mentioned.
Example:

```
def calculate(num1, num2, operator):
    if num2 == 0 :
        print("Division with zero")
        return 0
    if operator == "/" or operator == 'divide':
        output = float(num1) / float(num2)
        return output 

def main():
    calculate(4, 2, "/") # 2
    calculate(2, 0, "/") # 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```